# Download flickr images using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

google = "https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=Nike"
page = urlopen(google).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
img_tags = soup.find_all('img')
```

Now I'm stuck.

I'm trying to download all images on the link, can someone help me?

Comment: Which part troubles you? The url to the image is in `src` attribute of the `<img>`

Comment: @zvone can you tell me the command please

Comment: It is really not clear what your question is. Do you not know how to iterate through `img_tags`, or do you not know how to read the `src` from an image, or do you not know how to download an image once you get the url, or do you not know how to store the image after downloading it, or do you not know how to do anything in Python and want someone to write the code for you? The answer is very much different depending on the question, so you have to be clear about what you are asking.